# Laravel forge multiple domains

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-forge

I have a Laravel api that is hosted at api.example.com and my site domain in the Laravel forge panel is set to api.example.com

I now want to allow the same laravel installation to be accessible through 
somethingelse.example.com as well as *.somethingelse.example.com.

(Of course, In my code I am using the 
`Route::domain();` to show different things for each domain.)

My question is what do I put in my site domain. Do I put simply example.com or api.ppissis.com.cy or di I create a new site? I am not sure what to do.

Cloudflare subdomain is set and points to the server ip.

Right now the

[image]

Comment: Use `*.example.com` as site domain in Forge. All subdomain will work

Comment: Maybe [this answer](https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/forge/multiple-domains-on-a-single-laravel-app?page=0) can help? Adding vhost-lines to the nginx config file...

Comment: @LeventeOtta that doesn't take into account the second wildcard `*.somethingelse.example.com`